# Angularjs filter through array of object literals

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am new to angular js so please forgive me for this basic question.
I have an array of object literals and I want to add filter in angular js according to particular field type.

Array of object literals:

```
 var todos= [{text: 'To-DO1', done: false,group:'Group1' }, {text: 'To-do2', done: false, group:'Group2' } ];
```

I am using this code:

```
<select  data-ng-model="selectOption" data-ng-options="item as item.gtype for item in items"> </select>
<li data-ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index | filter: selectOption.gtype ">
```

Above filter is not working

For populating the select I am using :

```
$scope.items = [                  
  {gtype:'Group1'},                         
  {gtype:'Group2'},`enter code here`
  {gtype:'Group3'},
  {gtype:'Group4'},
  {gtype:'Group5'}
];
```

Could someone please help me through ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `track by $index`. The correct place for it is at the end of the expression, after the filter (see [ngRepeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat))...

```
<li data-ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: selectOption.gtype track by $index">
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d53E5/)

Edit: As requested, here's an updated fiddle to show an alternate message if filter produces nothing...

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wY388/)

Comment: One more thing Anthony, If I want to display a message if nothing is present for that specific group then how can this be done ?

Comment: Check out the new fiddle I added to the answer. You can stash away the filtered results into a scope variable and use it in ngShow/ngHide.